# Is there a socket for SOP8 packaging with SOP8 pins?

Tags: flash, soc, sop

[image]

25Q128 is a flash memory for an IP camera. I want to dump its firmware but also try to write my own firmware. I have all the soldering equipment to remove it safely. I also bought the breakout board for SOP8 package so I can solder the flash memory in to dump it. However, if I want to test lots of firmwares, then I can't keep soldering it back and forth on every new firmware.

Is there such thing as a socket that I can solder in the place of this flash memory so I can insert it there?

Another option would be to solder wires into it but I have the feeling that powering the flash memory might power adjacent things that might try to read/write into it, makign impossible for me to do a clean write/read, so I guess my only option is to desolder and put it into a socket.

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is a ZIF socket.

Comment: Well, there's [this one](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4726), but only for wide SOIC packages. I'm not sure if one exists for the more common narrow SOIC-8.

Comment: There are test clips that clip on the SOIC leads. Probably would work if you just put the part down on a insulating surface.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany what part down and what would be an insulating surface? Do you have a picture? Are you talking about doing this without unsoldering? Thank you very much

Comment: Eg. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13153  They're intended for programming the EEPROM in-circuit, which may or may not be possible in any given case.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany when you say it may not be possible, is it because powering the circuit can power other things that interfere, or that some flash circuits can be locked for some reason?

Comment: Yes, either one. Maybe the master can be held in reset to allow in-circuit programming.

Comment: Some cameras' firmware is field-updateable.   Does the manufacturer have a firmware update on this model, and can you decode its content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an SOIC clip. You can use this to interact with the serial flash without desoldering.

[image]

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13153
These are also available on Ebay and from other sources

These will work on any SOIC package with matching lead spacing regardless of width (that winbond package is wider than the standard ones)

They also make them for 16 pin packages though those are much less common.